# C# Getting Text from object in web page

Tags: c#, html, text-extraction

I'm trying to recreate an old C# application of mine that streams from an online radio station. Problem with the old one is, it loaded an entire web page just to display a certain area of it, which takes more resources that I would deem necessary. So, now I'm rewriting the entire application, and am looking for a way how I can retrieve text from the following code on the website:

```
 <div id="now" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
    <div class="scroll" style="margin-left: 0.000px;">
        <div id="title">SONG_NAME</div>
        <div id="artist">SONG_ARTIST</div>  
    </div>
 </div>
```

This piece is constantly updated on the page, with the name and artist of the current song.

id="title" is the name of the song and id="artist" is the artist of the song.

I would like to retrieve the name and artist every say, 10 seconds or so.

Any idea what code to use for this ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this if you don't own the web site since you have to request the website just as any other user would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to pull the entire page back. The main considerations are:

- You could request the html as [uncompressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx) and open the stream using [`HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) and then read up until the end of the block you need (you'll need to analyse the text as you go), and finally call [`HttpWebResponse.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.close%28loband%29.aspx) to close the stream and release the connection
- If the entire response is compressed it may be more efficient to get the whole thing anyway before decompressing.

You need to test which is more efficient for the specific page you are scraping.

So the usual way is to retrieve the whole html stream, then use regex to find the block you need, and just keep your code simple.

**Recommendation**

If you want to keep it *really* simple then look at [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which is even on NuGet to use with Visual Studio 2012. It makes working with html scraping very simple.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will indeed have a look at the HTMLAgilityPack, as it appears to be what I'm looking for. I prefer using less but efficient coding as dragging someone's computer down just to stream some audio isn't quite what one would want. This application is mainly just to build up a programmers profile and for me to study C# -> HTML communication and data extraction.